# Access nested JsonNode elements and separate by comma

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I have the following Json object:

```
 myJson = {1: {"grade": "A"}, 23: {"grade": "B"} }
```

I would like to iterate through the grades and if there is more than one grade, then I'd like to have the following string:

"A, B"

Separated by comma. If there is one element, then only "A".

How do I loop through the nested json object to delimit them by comma ? It is a JsonNode Jackson.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `JSON` payload is not valid and you need to enable `JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES` option. Also, you need to register `KotlinModule`.

Simple example could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.registerKotlinModule
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.stream.Collectors

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val jsonFile = File("src/main/resources/test.json").absoluteFile
    val mapper = ObjectMapper()
        .registerKotlinModule()
        .findAndRegisterModules()
        .enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES)
    val grades = mapper.readValue<ObjectNode>(jsonFile)
        .findValues("grade")
        .stream()
        .map { v -> v.asText() }
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
    System.out.println(grades)
}
```

Above code prints:

```
A, B
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the desired result like this (Java):

```java
String s = myJson.findValuesAsText("grade").stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```